# Innodb Cluster upgradeMetadata on broken cluster

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster

We have a cluster of 3 nodes, 2 of them are offline (missing) and I cannot get them to rejoin the cluster automatically only the master is Online.

Usually, you can use innodb admin:

var cluster = dba.getCluster();

but I cannot use the cluster instance because the metadata is not up to date. But I cannot upgrade the meta data because the missing members are required to be online to use dba.upgradeMetadata(). (Catch 22)

I tried to dissolve the cluster by using:

var cluster = dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage();

cluster.dissolve({force:true});

but this requires the metadata to be updated as well.

Question is, how do I dissolve the cluster completely or upgrade the metadata so that I can use the cluster. methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "chicken-egg" issue was fixed in MySQL Shell 8.0.20. dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage() is now allowed in such situation:

*BUG#30661129 – DBA.UPGRADEMETADATA() AND DBA.REBOOTCLUSTERFROMCOMPLETEOUTAGE() BLOCK EACH OTHER*

More info at: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-shell-adminapi-whats-new-in-8-0-20/

Comment: That's awesome! Yeah it was a real annoyance. I'm glad to see they're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cluster where each node upgrades to the latest version of mysql and the cluster isn't fully operational and you need to update your metadata for mysqlsh, you'll need to use an older version of mysqlsh for example, https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/shell/ to get the cluster back up and running. Once it is up and running you can use the dba.upgrademetadata on the R/W node - make sure you update all of your routers or they will lose connection.